# How to calculate proper keyboard contentInset for UIScrollView inside of a modally presented form sheet UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uikit

I am having an issue in which relying on `convertRect` to properly report a y position to use to calculate a `contentInset` is not working on iOS 12. This approach used to work on earlier iOS versions:

```
@objc func keyboardVisibilityChanged(notification: Notification) {
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {
        assertionFailure()
        return
    }

    let keyboardScreenEndFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let keyboardViewEndFrame = scrollView.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: view.window!)

    if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {
        scrollView.contentInset = .zero
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = .zero
    } else {
        let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: (keyboardViewEndFrame.origin.y - keyboardViewEndFrame.size.height) , right: 0)
        scrollView.contentInset = insets
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
    }
}
```

However, this code, while achieving extremely close visual results, is not exact and also breaks on iPhone, where the modal is presented fullscreen.

[image: Broken Inset]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple [states](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW16) in their documentation:

> Note: The rectangle contained in the UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey
>   and UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey properties of the userInfo
>   dictionary should be used only for the size information it contains.
>   Do not use the origin of the rectangle (which is always {0.0, 0.0}) in
>   rectangle-intersection operations. Because the keyboard is animated
>   into position, the actual bounding rectangle of the keyboard changes
>   over time.

So I came up with the following solutions that seems to work well on iOS 13, 12 and 11, including safe areas, modal form sheets, and hardware keyboards):

```
// MARK: - Keyboard Notifications
@objc func keyboardVisibilityChanged(notification: Notification) {       
    if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {
        scrollView.contentInset = .zero
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = .zero
    } else {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
            let value = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue,
            let window = view.window else {
                assertionFailure()
                return
        }

        let keyboardEndFrameInWindowCoordinates = value.cgRectValue
        let viewFrameInWindowCoordinates = window.convert(scrollView.frame,
                                                          from: scrollView.superview)

        let contentInsetBottom: CGFloat

        // If the keyboard is below us, no need to do anything.
        // This can happen when a hardware keyboard is attached to a modal form sheet on iPad
        if keyboardEndFrameInWindowCoordinates.origin.y >= viewFrameInWindowCoordinates.maxY {
            contentInsetBottom = 0
        } else {
            let bottomEdgeOfViewInWindowBottomCoordinates = window.frame.maxY - viewFrameInWindowCoordinates.maxY
            contentInsetBottom = keyboardEndFrameInWindowCoordinates.height - bottomEdgeOfViewInWindowBottomCoordinates - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        }

        let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,
                             left: 0,
                             bottom: contentInsetBottom,
                             right: 0)

        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
    }
}
```